# Wait for Android animation to finish

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

I was wondering if anyone could help me out, I've been looking everywhere for usefull help, but found nothing. I have four `View` elements (`Button`s), and I need to animate them, in random order, one after the other. I've tried waiting for `Animation.hasEnded()`, that just freezes the entire app. Also I tried waiting for an `AnimationListener` to change a boolean from `onAnimationEnd()`, but that also froze the app. Both `Thread.sleep()` and `SystemClock.sleep()` for waiting gave the same result. Please, can someone help me?

Comment: can you give us more code about the way how you wait for the animation?and I don't think you need to call thread.sleep() or systemclock.sleep in the onAnimationEnd()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

First, create a member for a random button array:

```
private Button[] mRandomButtonsOrder;
```

Then, initialize your random button order:

```
List<Button> myButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();

        myButtons.add(btn1); // Add all your buttons to this array.
        myButtons.add(btn2);
        myButtons.add(btn3);
        myButtons.add(btn4);

        mRandomButtonsOrder = new Button[myButtons.size()]; // This is a member of the activity!

        Random random = new Random();
        int index; 

        for (int i = 0; i < myButtons.size(); i++)
        {
            do
            {
                index = random.nextInt() % mRandomButtonsOrder.length;
            } while (mRandomButtonsOrder[index] != null);

            mRandomButtonsOrder[index] = myButtons.get(0);
            myButtons.remove(0);
        }

        initiateAnimationOnButton(0);
```

Now, here's the initateAnimationOnButton method:

```
private void initiateAnimationOnButton(final int buttonIndex)
    {
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta); // Just a sample using TranslateAnimation
        animation.setDuration(1000);

        if (buttonIndex < mRandomButtonsOrder.length - 1)
        {
            animation.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
                {
                    initiateAnimationOnButton(buttonIndex + 1);                         
                }
            });
        }

        Button btn = mRandomButtonsOrder[buttonIndex];
        btn.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

Hope this helps :)